# How can I write a greeting in classic ASP using a mixture of HTML and ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript, session-variables

Essentially I want to create a greeting that takes the username that is stored in a session variable when the user logs in and forms a greeting message that would go something like this:

Hello (username)!

My code looks like this at the moment but I'm getting error messages.

```
<%
dim greetingName
greetingName =  Session("username")

Response.write("Hello")greetingName"!"

%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work using `+` to concatenate the values:

```
<%
dim greetingName
greetingName = Session("username")
response.write "Hello " + greetingName + "!"
%>
```

Comment: Cheers! Worked a treat.

Comment: Use `&` for string concatenation, not `+`.